# Two eps sub-figures with one legend

Tags: eps, gnuplot, epslatex, histogram

I have two figures and I want to have them as two-subfigures with one legend, and separate numbers with commas on the y-axis (like 10,000 or 1,000,000).

This is what I currently have:

[image]

I tried to use "set multiplot layout 1,2" but it didn't work properly.

[image]

Here's my script:

```
set term postscript eps color blacktext "Helvetica" 24

set output 'figure.eps'
set key outside
#set multiplot layout 1,2

set boxwidth 0.9 absolute
set style line 2 lc rgb 'black' lt 1 lw 1
set style histogram cluster gap 3
set style fill pattern border -1
set datafile missing '-'
set style data histograms
set grid ytics

set xtics border in scale 0,0 nomirror rotate by -45  autojustify
set xtics norangelimit 
set xtics ()
set logscale y
plot "A.dat" using 3:xtic(2) title "A" ls 2, \
            '' using 4 title "B" ls 2, \
            '' using 5 title "C" ls 2, \
            '' using 6 title "D" ls 2

set datafile missing "?"
set logscale y
set style line 2 lc rgb 'black' lt 1 lw 1
set style histogram cluster gap 3
set style fill pattern border -1
set grid ytics

plot "B.dat" using 3:xtic(1) title "A" ls 2, \
            '' using 4 title "B" ls 2, \
            '' using 5 title "C" ls 2, \
            '' using 6 title "D" ls 2

unset multiplot
```

And data files, A.dat:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G
27  0.2 653.265 388.834 12.396  1.898   57406951
27  0.4 1514.187    892.661 97.012  4.224   129889867
```

B.dat:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G
25  0.6 312.987 216.049 54.973  1.085   33480428
28  0.6 3265.277    ?   558.423 8.769   268065210
29  0.6 7163.007    ?   1175.738    17.665  536407888
30  0.6 15958.110   ?   2620.629    36.811  1073243951
31  0.6 ?   ?   5361.464    74.357  2145001741
```

Comment: Since the legends are being created outside LaTeX, the best you can do is crop the images to either show or not show a legend.

Comment: @JohnKormylo How can I create it inside latex? I tried plotting two separate plots and combine them in one figure in latex using "\begin{subfigure}", but still couldn't add the legend using latex

Comment: AFAIK, you can't create eps with any LaTeX package..  At best you can submit an external program to create an image, the display the resulting file with LaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your multiplot you can `unset key` for the first plot to not get the legend, and for the second plot you can explicitly place the legend using `at x,y` where x,y are in the co-ordinate system of the plot. This may not be perfect as the resulting EPS bounding box does not seem to include the displaced legend, so you may need to edit the resulting PostScript.

To get comma separation of the thousands groups, I understand that you should be able to get your locale to do this for you, by using `set format "%'.0f"` but this didn't work for me, even with `LC_ALL=en_US` in the environment. An alternative is to fix the resulting PostScript using `sed` to add commas.  For example, add the line

```
set format sprintf("XYZ%'.0f")
```

where XYZ is some arbitrary string that will not appear in your output, then post-process your output with the script:

```
sed -i '
/XYZ/{
 :loop
 s/\(XYZ.*[0-9]\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)/\1,\2/
 tloop
 s/XYZ//
}
' figure.eps
```

Initially, you would have lines like

```
[ [(Helvetica) 240.0 0.0 true true 0 (XYZ100000)]
```

in your file, and the above will replace the `XYZ100000` by `100,000`.

[image]

For the above I used `set key at 13,10000` before the second plot and removed `set key outside`.

Comment: That's much helpful! Thank you so much. I created two separate plots using gnuplot, one has y-label, and the other has the legend on the right side, then modified the eps files using Sublime (text editor) to separate numbers with commas on y-axis, and finally combined the two plots in latex (subfigure). The result is sufficient and pretty close to what I needed.